# how to use gsoap without installing it in ubuntu?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gsoap

i am working in c++ under ubuntu. is there a way for using gsoap without installing it?

I did install it. i've copied all the gsoap dependencies....and now i would like to delete it and try to see if it's working.

what is your opinion?
THX. Appreciate

Comment: It would be nice of you to answer the followups people left on your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731782/undefined-reference-to-a-class-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gSoap is a compile-time tool, there's no runtime stuff to leave installed. From the moment you compiled the C++ side wrappers into library or exe, you only need to ship the files that wrap access to the target language (Python, java, whatever you chose).

You can safely uninstall gsoap and test.